# How to evaluate unhandled exception properties in immediate window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception, immediate-window

I have an unhandled exception that causes the Exception Assistant dialog box to appear.

When I click on View Detail..., the exception itself has some values in it's custom object model that will not evaluate in the property grid, but I know I can evaluate it in the immediate window. (In this case the property grid won't let me drill down into a collection, but there can be other cases)

**Without altering the code to add a try block**, how can I go to the immediate window and evaluate expressions on the unhanded exception?

The answer will probably be some magic that I just don't know yet, like ?this.CurrentException or

something involving `System.Diagnostics.StackFrame` or who knows. Something clever.

There is a way to navigate to it using the debugger thread, but that's quite complicated. If you can take that and make it simple with a wrapper that might be a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you try setting the debugger to break when the exception is thrown instead of just when it is User-unhandled?

To do this go to VS2010 main menu and select the 'Debug' menu
Next select 'Exceptions...'

That will bring up a dialog like:
[image: Debug -> Exceptions.. menu]

Select the Thrown column

Now when your exception is thrown and you should be able to evaluate your local variables in the Immediate window.

In the Locals tab I can see the $exception variable:
[image: Local variables contains $exception]

I'm able to use the "$exception" variable in the immediate window:
[image: Immediate Window accessing $exception]

**Update:** 
Also for easy toggling of Exception handling I recommend using the [Exception Breaker Visual Studio Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/50091e25-9e75-40d3-9780-a05892f474de), which allows you to toggle break on exception handling on and off from the tool bar instead of having to drill into the Debug menu.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to evaluate the unhandled exception itself. Visual Studio is breaking when I have the exception I'm interested in. Do you know what I would type in the immediate window to evaluate expressions involving the unhandled exception?

Comment: I'm able to access it via "$exception" in VS2010. I've updated the post with images.

Comment: I know you mentioned that you don't see "$exception" as a variable, but with the "break when an exception is: Thrown" checked it is there for me. I tried it and the variable is not there when the "Thrown" box is unchecked.

Comment: Thank you for making that distinction! that works for me :-) I think that's as good of an answer as there is for this version. I hope in 2012 the checkbox won't have to be checked.

Comment: I want to add, that you can uncheck Thrown in the Exceptions dialog if you turn off the Exception Assistant in Debugging Options. I don't know why they are mutually exclusive, but that's probably as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Visual Studio 2010 but in Visual Studio 2012 when an unhandled exception occurs it's shown in the `Locals` window with the name `$exception`.

Comment: We are using Visual Studio 2010, because we like the colored icons. (Just kidding), but we are stuck with that version. It does not appear in the Locals window. I tried the expression in the watch window and no luck.

Comment: I don't see $exception int he locals windows in Visual Studio 2015 either.

Answer (score 0):

> there is a property that will not evaluate in the property grid

If the property can't be evaluated, the debugger won't help you *as you have seen*; hence the immediate window would just do the same.

I had a invalid property such that it would throw an exception in VS2010 and cause the debugger to crash when I attempted to evaluate it. Nulls being returned from properties were not nice to the debugger.

I recommend that you go `old school` on the issue and put [Trace.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) within the property and elsewhere and monitor the write reports in the output window instead.

[How to trace and debug in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788)

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify. Sorry for the confusion. I'm not debugging a property or expression in my code. The expression I want to evaluate involves the unhandled exception and it's part of the exceptions object graph. Thanks.